# Order by not working with Group by in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

```
$loginuserID = $this->session->userdata("loginuserID");

$this->db->select('notice_x_user.*,notice.*,classes.*,sub_courses.*,,notice.status as studentStatus,notice.date as noticeDate');
$this->db->from('notice_x_user');
$this->db->join('notice','notice_x_user.noticeID = notice.noticeID', 'LEFT');
$this->db->join('classes', 'classes.ClassesID = notice.classesID', 'LEFT');
$this->db->join('sub_courses', 'sub_courses.sub_coursesID = notice.sub_coursesID', 'LEFT'); 
$wheres = "(notice_x_user.userID = '".$loginuserID."' and notice_x_user.usertype = 'Support') or notice.userID = '".$loginuserID."'";
$this->db->where($wheres);
$this->db->order_by('notice.noticeID', 'DESC'); 
$this->db->group_by('notice.noticeID');
```

I am join four table where I get correct data but the problem is that order by is not working while using group by. So, How can I do this? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: its problem, you can use `max()` if some max value needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> use select_max for getting the max noticeID

```
$this->db->select('notice_x_user.*,notice.*,classes.*,sub_courses.*,,notice.status as studentStatus,notice.date as noticeDate');
$this->db->select_max('notice.noticeID' , 'noticeID');
$this->db->from('notice_x_user');
$this->db->join('notice','notice_x_user.noticeID = notice.noticeID', 'LEFT');
$this->db->join('classes', 'classes.ClassesID = notice.classesID', 'LEFT');
$this->db->join('sub_courses', 'sub_courses.sub_coursesID = notice.sub_coursesID', 'LEFT'); 
$wheres = "(notice_x_user.userID = '".$loginuserID."' and notice_x_user.usertype = 'Support') or notice.userID = '".$loginuserID."'";
$this->db->where($wheres);
$this->db->order_by('noticeID', 'DESC'); 
$this->db->group_by('notice.noticeID');
```

Answer (score 0):

Grouping statements must be used **before** ordering statements, otherwise you'll get a MySQL error.

Just put the statements in the correct order:

```
$this->db->group_by('notice.noticeID');
$this->db->order_by('notice.noticeID', 'DESC');
```

and it'll work as expected

Comment: Isn't CI query builder taking care of the correct sequence of group and order ?

Comment: I'm under the impression that the query builder class should take care of the correct sequence, but it doesn't hurt to keep things neat and tidy on our end too :) I'm yet to test on my own sandbox how well does it manage the incorrect sequence